How can I use `aws sam package` when I have multiple Lambdas using an image type?
I have a Lambda that is an image type, and so have a Docker file that goes with it. In the CI/CD pipeline we have set up, during the build phase, I can run the following command:
sam package --template template.yml --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template-file packaged.yml --image-repository $ECR_REPO_URI

This has worked out because it'll upload the image and associate it to the Lambda automatically without having to specify the ImageUri in the CloudFormation template. However, I'm trying to plan for the future, and there will surely be a time when we have more than one Lambda of the image type.
My question is, how would I handle something like that? From what I've gathered, I should have an ECR repo per application, or per Lambda in this case. And I don't see a way to specify multiple repositories.
